# Recall a method from a certain point

Tags: java

I want to rerun this method from a certain point when a condition (else) is met, I know I need to create a new class/method for it, but not sure how since all my variables stay in the main method.

```
import java.util.*;

public class OddsAndEvens {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Let's play a game called Odds And Evens");

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("What is your name? ");

        //user name
        String name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Hi " + name + "Which do you choose? Odds or Evens ?");

        //user preference this is where I want to rerun the method from in else condition
        String pref = input.nextLine();


        if (pref.equals("Odds") || pref.equals("odds")) {

            System.out.println(name + " has picked odds ! Computer will be evens");

        } else if(pref.equals("Evens") || pref.equals("evens")) {
            System.out.println(name + " has picked evens! Computer will be odds");
        } else {
            System.out.println("please enter a valid answer");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new class. You could create a new method, put all the code you want to repeat in it, then just call the new method multiple times. Or you could use a loop. There are many ways to solve this, so this is quite broad of a question. Have you tried anything yet? Also, what part do you want to repeat from?

Comment: One short tipp: You can use the String method `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of doing the 2 equals calls you currently do.

Comment: @Carcigenicate hello, you can see where I want to rerun the method from if you look at my second comment line.

Comment: you need to accept the answer instead updating title to "solved"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one way is to do as Valentin said and just create a method you can recall.
You could also just use a while loop that keeps on asking for the "odds" or "evens" until the user inputs one of the two. 
Something along the lines of:

```
    String pref = "";

    while(!pref.equalsIgnoreCase("odds") && !pref.equalsIgnoreCase("evens")) {
        pref = input.nextLine();
        if (pref.equals("Odds") || pref.equals("odds")) {
            System.out.println(name + " has picked odds ! Computer will be evens");

        } else if (pref.equals("Evens") || pref.equals("evens")) {
            System.out.println(name + " has picked evens! Computer will be odds");
        } else {
            System.out.println("please enter a valid answer");
        }
    }
```

You can shorten the code and make it cleaner by any means but you should get the main idea.

Comment: thank you for this, I will be using equalsIgnoreCase from now on :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a new class. You can just copy your code and put it in a new method like this:

```
private static void playOddsAndEvens() {
    //here comes your code that was written in the main method.
}
```

Your class would then look like this:

```
public class OddsAndEvens {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playOddsOrEvens();
    }

    private static void playOddsAndEvens() {
        //here comes your code that was written in the main method.
    }
}
```

If you want to use this method in another class, you can make your method playOddsAndEvens() public instead of private.

From then on, you can call your method from anywhere you want as many times as you want.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, I can recall the method no problem but here's the issue, I don't want it to rerun the whole method so in other words I don't want it to ask for your name again when you enter an invalid preference. But when I try to place " private static void playOddsAndEvens()" after the preference question, it cannot find the variables from main method.

Answer (score 1):

There are good answers here for you, but an alternative is to [separate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) all the necessary functions into separate methods:

**1)** Call a `getUserInput()` method

**2)** Call a `checkOption()` method with the user input

**3a)** if the input equals your options, print your desired outcome

**3b)** if it doesn't equal it, call the `getUserInput()` method again

So something along the lines of:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getUserInput();
}

static void getUserInput() {
    System.out.println("enter odds or evens");
    String pref = input.nextLine();
    checkOption(pref);
}

static void checkOption(String option) {
    if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("odds") || option.equalsIgnoreCase("evens")) {
        result(option);
    } else {
        getUserInput();
    }
}

static void result(String s) {
    System.out.println("You chose " + s);
}
```

[Example](https://ideone.com/aXOtwU)

Comment: I did not know about these calls, thank you for sharing